# Google maps plugin - showing controls but not data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to incorporate using Google maps into a webpage I am developing. I am wanting to display the map on tab#5 of a tab control.  When my code runs, tab#5 fills in with a completely gray background, the Google logo in the bottom left corner, zoom and pan controls, but nothing else.  There is NO map data, streets, option for satellite view, etc.

Here is what I am doing...
I am including the Google JS file...

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
```

The actually code itself is...

```
   var map;
function initMap() {
  console.log('Console running 5')  ;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('analysisTabMap'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 16,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true
  });
}


    initMap();
```

Console shows 'Console running 5; message, so my code is executing.  I thought it might be a zoom factor, so i have zoomed both in and out; yet I still see nothing but gray.

What am I doing wrong?  Here is what my tab shows...
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code is working just fine.
Could it be that another script on your pages causes an error that breaks the loading of the map?

http://jsfiddle.net/zvjr80w3/

HTML

```
<div id="analysisTabMap"></div>
```

CSS

```
#analysisTabMap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  console.log('Console running 5')  ;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('analysisTabMap'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 16,
    zoomControl: true,
    scaleControl: true
  });
}


initMap();
```